# Are some vegetables from China being labeled as "Product of New Zealand" in Australia?

Tags: law, australia, trade

There are a number of claims going around on Facebook that foods purchased in Australia which are labelled as being from New Zealand are from China.  This [2014 article](https://www.macrobusiness.com.au/2014/02/china-uses-nz-for-backdoor-food-entry-to-australia/) in *Macro Business* explains:

> It works like this: Vegetables from China are sent to New Zealand where they are mixed with big name brands and sent on to Australia
>   where they are sold to the unsuspecting consumer.
>
> This is made possible by a loophole in our trade agreements with
>   Australia and also that country’s unwillingness to adopt country of
>   origin labelling. While it is not mandatory here either most companies
>   at least pay homage to it…

Is this happening? Is it legal under Australian food labelling laws?